# In Wildfly, "/" is rewritten to "/index.html", bypassing RequestMapping("/")

Tags: spring-mvc, wildfly, undertow

I am migrating a Spring MVC app from JBoss 7.1.1 to Wildfly 8.1, which has required (encouraged?) me to use the new ["undertow" module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Undertow+%28web%29+subsystem+configuration) instead of the older "web" module.  Things are coming right along, except that now requests to "`/`", which used to invoke the controller method annotated with `@RequestMapping("/")`, no longer reach the controller method.  Instead, it appears that such requests are being immediately rewritten (not redirected) to "`/index.html`".  Since I don't have (and have never needed) such a file, all requests for "`/`" are now generating 404 errors.

Interestingly, all of the *other* `@RequestMapping`-annotated controller methods continue to function normally.

Here is the relevant snippet from my `standalone.xml` file.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="4194304"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config development="true"/>
    </servlet-container>
</subsystem>
```

I suspect that when the `subsystem` definition for Wildfly's undertow module does not explicitly declare a `handler`, Wildfly defaults to a `file` handler, which may be responsible for the the URL rewrites -- but I am not certain of this.

[Documentation about handlers](http://undertow.io/documentation/core/built-in-handlers.html) in the Undertow project, upon which Wildfly's undertow module is based, indicate support for a "Redirect" handler.  I have considered using this to work around the unexpected "/" rewriting, but it is not clear to me whether Wildfly's undertow module supports this, and if it does, how to configure it in `standalone.xml`.  Even if I was able, however, I think it would feel like a hack, and I'd prefer to get to the root of the problem (no pun intended) instead.

There are many S.O. questions describing disappointing `RequestMapping("/")` behavior, and many answers suggesting using other paths (such as `""`, `"/index"`, etc.), but don't forget: the existing (unchanged) code works just fine in JBoss 7.1.1.  (Also, none of those questions mention Wildfly, which is probably the key consideration for this question.)  Nevertheless, I experimented with the various suggestions and got nowhere.  It simply seems like the URL is being rewritten before it ever reaches the dispatcher servlet.

So, in summary, my question is:

> How can I get a Spring MVC app with `RequestMapping("/")` to run in Wildfly 8.1 as it does in JBoss 7.1.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Wildfly, if your `web.xml` doesn't have a `<welcome-file-list>` element, then one is provided for you, as if you had configured it this way:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

With this default configuration, when Wildfly receives a request for for "`/`", the path is automatically rewritten as `index.html`.  This path will then not match the controller method annotated with `RequestMapping("/")`.

JBoss 7 apparently behaves differently, perhaps only referring to the welcome file list after failing to find a matching servlet.

Whatever the cause, you can work around the new behavior by explicitly defining your own welcome file list and including, as the last `<welcome-file>` element, an empty welcome file:

```
 <welcome-file></welcome-file>
```

This allows Wildfly to rewrite "`/`" as "`/`", in turn allowing the request for "`/`" to be processed by the servlet dispatcher (provided that its `url-pattern` is set to `/`).  The servlet dispatcher will then invoke the controller method annotated with `RequestMapping("/")`.